# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://192.168.1.195:85/tranxavApi/public/api/signup

Tags: android, android-volley

Maybe this problem has been posted before  but it does not solve my case. I am trying to send data from android to mysql database using laravel as the backend. I have developed the restful Api. This is my code.

```
         try {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUpActivity.this);

                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                jsonBody.put("username","amz");
                jsonBody.put("email","amz@gmail.com");
                jsonBody.put("password","fashion");
                jsonBody.put("vCode","12345");
                jsonBody.put("type","coupons");
                final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        String responseString = "";
                        if (response != null) {
                            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                            // can get more details such as response.headers
                        }
                        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Api URL

```
http://192.168.1.195:85/tranxavApi/public/api/signup
```

E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.NetworkError

Laravel Code

```
 public function signUp(Request $request){
    $success = "Successful";
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
    }
    User::create([
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'username' => $request->get('username'),
        'password' => Hash::make($request->get('password')),
        'vCode' => $request->get('vCode')
    ]);

    return response()->json(['success'=> $success], $this->successStatus);
}
```

My error Log

> E/Volley: [164] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code
>   500 for http://192.168.1.195:85/tranxavApi/public/api/signup
>
> E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.NetworkError

No authorization is needed. All your answers will be highly appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/google/volley/issues/104  Read this link

Comment: Is the API working in Postman?

Comment: If i post my data with postman it goes through

Comment: Is it Json request to server?

Comment: @OshabaChukwudi What you are (successfully) posting in Postman probably doesn't match what you're _actually_ posting with the above code. Either get the sender to print/dump exactly what it's sending, or the API to print/dump what it received.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

```
{     
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("Accept", "application/json");

                return params;  
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `JsonObjectRequest`

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUpActivity.this);


JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                jsonBody.put("username","amz");
                jsonBody.put("email","amz@gmail.com");
                jsonBody.put("password","fashion");
                jsonBody.put("vCode","12345");
                jsonBody.put("type","coupons");

JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(URL,jsonBody,
       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               try {
                   //Process os success response
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
           }
       });

    requestQueue.add(requestQueue);
```

the postman success message
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried it but gives the same error

Comment: Can you share your postman success image so that i can help you

Comment: I have shared it

Comment: Are you testing in the same network?in postma ur trying localhost:85 port so

Comment: am using localhost

Comment: Are you using emulator or mobile?because same network only it will work

Comment: am using emulator but i guess the problem now is from laravel create the user

Comment: are you using http://localhost:85/tranxavApi/public/api/signup or http://192.168.1.195:85/tranxavApi/public/api/signup
?

Comment: am using 192.168.1.195:85/tranxavApi/public/api/signup ?

Comment: use this and check once localhost:85/tranxavApi/public/api/signup

Comment: the values post from android to laravel but when it gets to create in laravel it returns the exception

Comment: oh try to fix that first

Comment: i have tried localhost but its given bad url error on volley. thanks I really appreciate your effort

Comment: Ok happy to help you...but this issue is strange

Comment: thanks alot. can i have your email so that when I encounter a challenge I can send you a mail